# How can a custom filter be added to the HttpPipeline using afBedSheet?

Tags: fantom, afbedsheet

The [afBedSheet documentation](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afBedSheet/index.html) says that "Filters can be used to address cross cutting concerns such as authorisation." and shows this code snippet:

```
@Contribute { serviceType=HttpPipeline# }
static Void contributeHttpPipeline(OrderedConfig conf, AuthFilter myAuthFilter) {
  conf.addOrdered("AuthFilter", myAuthFilter, ["after: BedSheetFilters"])
}
```

I'm trying to implement an AuthFilter (a dummy now but to be evolved into a real AuthFilter) but I can't get it to work:

```
using afBedSheet

const mixin AuthFilter : HttpPipelineFilter { }

internal const class AuthFilterImpl : AuthFilter {

    internal new make(|This|in) { in(this) }

    override Bool service(HttpPipeline handler) {
        echo("Dummy AuthFilter invoked!")
        return handler.service
    }
}
```

I can successfully build the project, but when I run it and invoke any HTTP service I get the error below. I believe I have to declare or annotate my AuthFilter as an [afIoc](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afIoc/) service, but don't know where or how. Can anyone show me how, please?

```
Thread Locals:
  ThreadStash.01.BedSheetModule.0017.perThreadState: fan.afIoc.ModuleServices@1ab5e0b
  ThreadStash.01.HttpRequest.0001.headers: fan.afBedSheet.HttpRequestHeaders@1ab6087
  afIoc::ThreadStash.counter: 13
  web.req: fan.wisp.WispReq@4e62cc
  web.res: fan.wisp.WispRes@387bc2
  web.session: 060f9951-41f1-e500-0fc2-0019b971d079
[05:27:18 05-Nov-13] [err] [web] Internal error processing: /info
  afIoc::IocErr: No dependency matches type mt::AuthFilter.
Ioc Operation Trace:
  [ 1] Locating dependency by type 'afBedSheet::HttpPipeline'
  [ 2] Creating REAL Service 'HttpPipeline'
  [ 3] Creating Service 'HttpPipeline' via a builder method 'afBedSheet::BedSheetModule.buildHttpPipeline'
  [ 4] Determining injection parameters for afBedSheet::HttpPipeline buildHttpPipeline(afBedSheet::HttpPipelineFilter[] filters, afIoc::PipelineBuilder bob, afIoc::Registry reg)
  [ 5] Looking for dependency of type afBedSheet::HttpPipelineFilter[]
  [ 6] Gathering ORDERED configuration of type afBedSheet::HttpPipelineFilter[]
  [ 7] Determining injection parameters for sys::Void contributeHttpPipeline(afIoc::OrderedConfig conf, mt::AuthFilter
myAuthFilter)
  [ 8] Looking for dependency of type mt::AuthFilter
Stack Trace:
    afIoc::Utils.stackTraceFilter (Utils.fan:63)
    afIoc::RegistryImpl.dependencyByType (RegistryImpl.fan:243)
    afBedSheet::BedSheetWebMod.onService (BedSheetWebMod.fan:34)
    wisp::WispActor.doService (WispActor.fan:197)
    wisp::WispActor.process (WispActor.fan:78)
    wisp::WispActor.receive (WispActor.fan:48)
    concurrent::Actor._dispatch (Actor.java:228)
    concurrent::Actor._work (Actor.java:199)
    concurrent::ThreadPool$Worker.run (ThreadPool.java:255)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthFilter` does not *need* to be declared as a service - you could new up an instance in the contribute() method:

```java
@Contribute { serviceType=HttpPipeline# }
static Void contributeHttpPipeline(OrderedConfig conf) {

    authFilter := AuthFilterImpl()

    conf.addOrdered("AuthFilter", authFilter, ["after: BedSheetFilters"])
}
```

If `AuthFilter` has dependencies on other services (for example, it has fields annotated with `@Inject`) then [afIoc](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afIoc/#overview) should build the instance for you. The `OrderedConfig` and `MappedConfig` objects have a handy `autobuild()` method just for this:

```java
    authFilter := conf.autobuild(AuthFilterImpl#)
```

If you want `AuthFilter` to be injected into other services, or you want to contribute to it, then it needs to be defined as an [afIoc](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afIoc/#overview) service. Use the `bind()` method in your `AppModule` to do this:

```java
static Void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(AuthFilter#, AuthFilterImpl#)
}
```

It may then be parameter injected into the contribute method, just as you had in your example:

```java
@Contribute { serviceType=HttpPipeline# }
static Void contributeHttpPipeline(OrderedConfig conf, AuthFilter authFilter) {

    conf.addOrdered("AuthFilter", authFilter, ["after: BedSheetFilters"])
}
```

See [afIoc - definingServices](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afIoc/#definingServices) for more details. The [BedSheetModule](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afBedSheet/src-BedSheetModule.fan.html) may also be a good reference for afIoc examples.